# Why does my web crawler work on localhost but not in the docker container?

Tags: docker, web-scraping, web-crawler, apify, crawlee

I'm trying to create a web crawler using [crawlee and apify](https://crawlee.dev/docs/guides/docker-images) With NodeJS. This crawler works when I run on the localhost, but when I run on docker container, I receive a timeout error waiting for locator. The docker container was built correctly but when the web crawler starts running I get the timeout error.

I'm using Playwright and Firefox browser. I need to know, what are the possible reasons why this is happening?

The error:

```
INFO  PlaywrightCrawler: Collecting results from league 2

WARN  PlaywrightCrawler: Reclaiming failed request back to the list or queue. page.waitForSelector: Timeout 30000ms exceeded.
=========================== logs ===========================
waiting for locator('.vrl-MeetingsHeaderButton') to be visible
 ============================================================
at navigateToLeague (file:///home/myuser/dist/handlers/league.js:3:16)
```

The Dockerfile:

```
# Specify the base Docker image. You can read more about
# the available images at https://crawlee.dev/docs/guides/docker-images
# You can also use any other image from Docker Hub.
FROM apify/actor-node-playwright-firefox:16 AS builder

# Copy just package.json and package-lock.json
# to speed up the build using Docker layer cache.
COPY --chown=myuser package*.json ./

# Install all dependencies. Don't audit to speed up the installation.
RUN npm install --include=dev --audit=false

# Next, copy the source files using the user set
# in the base image.
COPY --chown=myuser . ./

# Install all dependencies and build the project.
# Don't audit to speed up the installation.
RUN npm run build

# Create final image
FROM apify/actor-node-playwright-firefox:16

# Copy just package.json and package-lock.json
# to speed up the build using Docker layer cache.
COPY --chown=myuser package*.json ./

# Install NPM packages, skip optional and development dependencies to
# keep the image small. Avoid logging too much and print the dependency
# tree for debugging
RUN npm --quiet set progress=false \
    && npm install --omit=dev --omit=optional \
    && echo "Installed NPM packages:" \
    && (npm list --omit=dev --all || true) \
    && echo "Node.js version:" \
    && node --version \
    && echo "NPM version:" \
    && npm --version \
    && rm -r ~/.npm

# Copy built JS files from builder image
COPY --from=builder --chown=myuser /home/myuser/dist ./dist

# Next, copy the remaining files and directories with the source code.
# Since we do this after NPM install, quick build will be really fast
# for most source file changes.
COPY --chown=myuser . ./


# Run the image. If you know you won't need headful browsers,
# you can remove the XVFB start script for a micro perf gain.
CMD ./start_xvfb_and_run_cmd.sh && npm run start:prod --silent
```

I was hoping that the dockerfile templates provided by apify would make my crawler work like it works locally